# Dynatrace Performance Metrics

Tags: apm, dynatrace

I am looking for the performance metrics that can be monitored using Dynatrace Application Monitoring tool. If they are categorized for different tiers (Web Server, Application Server, Database Server) that would be nice to have.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Dynatrace has a concept of Measures. Depending on the type of measure, e.g: # of SQL Calls we tell you which server caused these calls (App SErver 1, App Server 2, ...). For basic monitoring metrics such as CPU, Memory, Throughput, ... we also capture this for each individual tier.
If you put these measures on a chart you can select for which application, agent or agent group you want to show them. There is a drop down box in the Measure Selection Dialog.

Let me know if you want to know more. Also - feel free to use our own discussion forum on our community. A lot of these questions are already answered there: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DTFORUM/dynaTrace+Forums+Home

Comment: I was looking here: https://community.compuwareapm.com/community/display/DOCDT60/Application+Details#ApplicationDetails-Markers  It gives some of the metrics. But is there any single place where I can find the comprehensive list of metrics in Dynatrace? (without installing Dynatrace)

Comment: Hi. We capture a lot of metrics/measures. There is no page that lists of all of them. We cover app metrics such as SQL, Exceptions, Method Executions Times, Web Request Times but also Sys Metrics such as CPU, Memory, Garbage Collection, ...
We discuss lot of these metrics in our blogs as well - here is a good starting point: http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2015/01/28/key-performance-metrics-load-tests-beyond-response-time-part-ii/

If you need more info let me know. Happy to send you more info

Answer (score 0):

Dynatrace has the starter guide. You can examine from the link below for different tiers (Application Server, Database, Web, Service, Process etc.)

[Dynatrace Starter Guide](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/get-started/)

Regards